# How can I create an Apple Keynote Presentation from scratch?

Tags: java, xml, dom, keynote

I am trying to write a program that creates an Apple Keynote Slide. I was hoping to find some answers about creating apple's xml format (apxl) from scratch using Java. I have found a few documents pertaining to older versions of Keynote that allow such creation using Java DOM, but as far as the latest version of Keynote goes, I haven't had much luck. (btw I know that the .key file is a package, and that the apxl file is compressed .gz)

I have already read the following documents:

[1] https://developer.apple.com/appleapplications/keynote-apxl.html

[2] http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/01/07/keynote.html

... and many others. (stackoverflow will only let me post two links as a new person)

A google search will show you that there's not much documentation past 2004.

My question is, has anyone here successfully written something in Java to create, or add to, an apxl file for use with keynote?  If so, could you point me toward the documentation, tutorials, or sample code that you used?

I'm not looking for your code, I just can't find a viable set of instructions wherever I look.

Thanks

Comment: I would definitely [go the HTML way](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/) - will save you infinite time.

Comment: @moonwave99 That's really cool! I am going to suggest it to the team.

Comment: @WrksOnMyMachine - Did you find any solution for this !! I have the same question.

Comment: @gpothan I have not looked for a solution in 5 years. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

My colleague used the next approach to generate big MS .xls/.doc 2003 documents. He had a goal to make reports contained >10^6 rows. He just produced xml and made zip file - as does it MS Word/Excel.

The format of xml can be simply retrieved from sample documents: e.g. if you'd like to know how do text formatting - just create simple documents with it and analyse output files.
Of couse we had very tiny set of abilities, but basic text formatting and layout markups were implemented.

I'm not sure how many features do you need. But you may implement the same xml generation procedures after separate investigation of every formatting feature.